# Cannot delete posts in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, vote-to-delete

I just recently wished to get rid of one of my answers but could not find any way to delete it from within the Android app.

The only options I get in the menu are Edit, Flag and Share.

Comment: Confirmed on 1.0.16, though I think you might want to tap your answer menu instead: Share, Edit, Flag (no Delete)

Comment: Corrected my question.

Comment: The same issue exists for deleting Questions.

Comment: Not a bug; this functionality is not implemented yet.