# Opening notifications crashes the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, notifications

Anytime I try to open the notifications on the right in the Android app, the app crashes. "Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has stopped." But the new notification number clears. Happens both from within the app and from the android push notifications.

Comment: What version of the application are you using?

Comment: Its Version 1.0.51

Comment: Just to be clear, it's happening when you open the inbox list on the right (so the list doesn't open) versus crashing when you click on an item in it, right?

Comment: Correct. The list opens and is blank, and the loading thing spins for a second, then it crashes.

Comment: Odd, same version, no updates, and now it isn't crashing

Comment: it's crashing due to a specific notification time missing a title. It's gone to page two of your inbox now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in the current beta update, and will be fixed in the next non-beta release (anything with a version higher than 1.0.51) -- If you'd like, you can [join our testing group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app) to get the fix ASAP.

Comment: I'm going to leave this as not [status-completed] until the version is actually out, since marking it completed when only 600 people have access to it is a lie.

Comment: *ahem*, that's 599 people and a doorknob to you

Comment: As of today I have this same issue again. Newest version of Android and the App.

Comment: Having this issue in 2022.