# In the about page of the Android app; it says copyright 2014

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The title pretty much says it all.
Android app version: 1.0.57
Android version: 4.1.2

[image]

Comment: ["The date is supposed to be when it was published. So if content is ongoing then it could be a range or it could be the date of the most recent revision. If the site has had no changes then it should be the earliest date."](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8249/37527) recent version?

Comment: @Braiam The stack exchange network is still active & maintained, right?

Comment: @Braiam Version 1.0.57 was just released on Feb 16, 2015.

Comment: "Copyright" isn't year specific.  You don't have to copyright stuff every year on Jan 1.  You copyright it on year X and that copyright lasts for ... twenty years?  Thirty?  Not sure.  But you certainly don't have to update it erry gotdamn year.  That's not how it works.

Comment: I noticed that the website is copyrighted Toto 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next beta update (1.0.58+), and we're even correctly using a en-dash for listing the years, thanks for reporting this!

Comment: When 2016 will arrive will we have to start new bug report? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the about page is just a static HTML file, I considered adding javascript to it to dynamically generate the date but figured I wouldn't rob someone the rep for posting this same report next year :)

Comment: lol, like the way you think! :-D

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I reported this in a comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app#comment813984_245731 You didn't see?